# Как добавить в таблицу столбец с числами от 1 по порядку?

Tags: python, циклы

Есть таблица, содержащая перечень гипотез и соответствующий каждой гипотезе показатель ICE. Нужно добавить столбец с рейтингом.
Если отсортировать по убыванию значений столбца 'ice', то можно добавить столбец с числами по порядку от 1 до 9.

```
for i in range(len(hypothesis_ice)):
    hypothesis_ice['raiting_ice'] = i+1
```

[image: Исходная таблица]

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос написан так, что-бы всех запутать. Как добавить столбец с числами по порядку -  но ответ вроде бы самостоятельно написан уже в вопросе. Вроде бы "таблица" -  это датафрейм, но об этом ни слова.

В общем, если надо добавить просто столбец с числами от 1 до... в Pandas DataFrame с именем hypothesis_ice, то сделать это можно, например, так:

```
hypothesis_ice['raiting_ice']=np.arange(len(hypothesis_ice))[::-1]+1
```

Естественно, перед этим DataFrame надо отсортировать по нужному столбцу, но это - опять таки как следует из вопроса-  вы уже знаете как.

Если же вы вдруг имели ввиду что-то другое -  то попробуйте сформулировать свой вопрос явно и членораздельно.